# add two values with [[object valueForKey:@""] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

Tags: iphone, arrays, string

hy everyone,

i really need a helping hand here.
here is my problem: 
i have an array with objects which each has two attributes:
1 is an NSSTring name
2 is an NSSNumber price

now i want to run through the array and add all the values to a new string:

the problem is i need the following output.
name (from object 1) : price (from object 1) then new line (\n)
name (from object 2) : price (from object 2) then new line (\n) ... and so on...

would be great if someone could help me here.
with kind regards, thomas

Comment: What kind of objects do you have in your array? An instance of one of your class, a NSDictionary?

Comment: yes an instance of one of my classes sorry that i didnot mention it in the first place. thanks for the reply +g+

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// This contains your objects with names and prices;
NSArray *productArray;

...

// |listOfProducts| will be your string with all names and prices.
NSMutableString *listOfProducts = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

// Build the list of products
for (Product *product in productArray) {
    [listOfProducts appendFormat:@"%@: $%0.2f\n", product.name, product.price];
}
```

Comment: oh my god! thank you very very very much. when someone comes up with such a nice solution i always get rememberd that i still have to learn a lot. i wish you good luck. thanks thomas